# How to get integers saved into SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I have made a food calculator, which calculates calories (from food types) and weight (based on user input using EditText) and displays these in a TextView. How would I then take the value displayed in the textView and save it into an SharedPreference?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save the value, you write it to the SharedPreferences.

```
private static final String VALUE_TAG = "myTag";
Context c = this; //this for Activity. For Fragment use getActivity();
```

You always assign a value to a key, I called "myKey"

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putInt(VALUE_TAG, 5);
editor.apply();
```

And to retrieve it:

```
int defaultValue = 42;
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
int retrievedValue = sp.getInt(VALUE_TAG , defaultValue);
```

Where the 42 is the value returned if there is no value with the key "myKey";

Comment: `this` parameter inside `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()` method is the context of the application. 

Also, the String used for saving / getting a preference should be a `public static final String` field inside the class (to avoid spelling bugs)